# Is there any solidity ide and compiler app for android or other mobie OS?

Tags: solidity, compiler, android, ide

Please, I am teaching some secondary school pupils solidity and they wish to know if there are any IDEs and compiler apps for android devices.

They are young and most of them do not have PCs to practice at home. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: I dont think there is unfortunately. And i wouldnt recommand coding on a mobile device anyways

Answer (score 1):

Yes, REMIX IDE online works well on the phone. Make sure to tilt the screen and open the "Dekstop Site" button on the chrome etc

Answer (score 0):

[remix.ethereum.org](https://remix.ethereum.org/) works on my phone

Answer (score 0):

I guess u can use javascript syntax highlighting on acode app. It would be better then no syntax colour. And now you can completely learn solidity on android without remix.